# Show/hide help block if radio checked

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I need a form that displays an adjacent .help-block if a radio is checked, but hides the .help-block if the corresponding radio is unchecked. I must have my javascript wrong, because clicking any radio reveals all .help-block spans.

http://jsfiddle.net/utcwebdev/cwryu9ac/2/

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type="radio"]').next(".help-block").addClass('hidden');
      $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log($this);
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
          $('input[type="radio"]').next(".help-block").removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
          $('input[type="radio"]').next(".help-block").addClass('hidden');
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<link href="//www.utc.edu/_resources/css/kickstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="control-group">

  <label class="control-label" for="Q3"><strong>3. Are you comfortable creating, saving, and attaching files on your computer? </strong>
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="2">Yes. I am comfortable creating, saving, and attaching files on my computer.
      <span class="help-block">Very good. These are some of the technical skills you’ll need in an online course.</span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="0">No. I’m not comfortable creating, saving, and/or attaching files on my computer.
      <span class="help-block">You may need to seek assistance in acquiring these skills before taking an online class. </span>
    </label>

  </div>
  <!--/controls-->
</div>
<!--/control-group-->

<div class="control-group">

  <label class="control-label" for="Q4"><strong>4.  Do you stay on track without direct supervision, or do you work best when someone is there to supervise you and help keep you focused? </strong>
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="2">Yes. I am self-motivated.
      <span class="help-block">Being self-disciplined and organized are traits you’ll need to succeed in online learning.</span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="0">No. I need supervision
      <span class="help-block">In an online class, you’ll need to rely on yourself to keep track of assignments and due dates.</span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="1">Sometimes. At times I procrastinate.
      <span class="help-block">This could be a problem in an online course because it is your responsibility to keep track of assignments and due dates.  You’ll need to stay focused in order to succeed.</span>
    </label>

  </div>
  <!--/controls-->
</div>
<!--/control-group-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery change event is fired for the radio button you click on. So you need to code accordingly.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').next(".help-block").addClass('hidden');

    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        // Use this if you want to hide help-blocks of all questions
        //$('input[type="radio"]').next().addClass('hidden');

        // Use this if you want to hide other help-blocks of current question
        $('input[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').next().addClass('hidden');

        // Show help-block for selected button
        $this.next(".help-block").removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwryu9ac/5/

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Comment: @user1769915 glad to help.. Could you please accept the answer if you find it suitable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this`. Instead you're querying `input[type=radio]` inside your change function which selects all radio inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type="radio"]').next(".help-block").addClass('hidden');
      $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log($this);
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
          $this.next(".help-block").removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
          $this.next(".help-block").addClass('hidden');
        }
      });
    });
```

I'd like to add that you don't have to use jQuery to check if checkbox is checked. You may replace `$this.is(":checked")` with `this.checked` which is both faster and cleaner